# How can i Randomly display GROUP of content to user from my Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, shuffle

Hi there am building an android quiz application. I have all my necessary activities(result activity, question activity etc) I even have my Sqlite database with about 50 questions. For each game or session the user is given 10 questions which are answered and result given to the user. **What I want to achieve is each time the user opens the app I want a different set of 10 question should be showed to the user, since I have up to 50 questions**
E.g on each launch of the app say question 1-10 could be displayed, on next launch 11- to 20 and in that order. If the database questions have been exhausted it can repeat the order again. I want a group of  say 10 questions shuffled to the user on each launch. Its an offline app.
 Please any help (detailed will b appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain boolean column in table "QuestionAsked". When a set of question is asked or asked and attempted (Whichever logic you want to keep), update the boolean to true. Next time, when you go to fetch the questions, randomize questions with QuestionAsked=false. This will help you in getting unique questions.
Also, you can reset the column once all questions have been asked or no adequate questions remained to be queried.
Hope your question is well understood and that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you !, but pls do I add the boolean iin my SQL database.java file , and do I use the index to get asked questions??? Further how do I know the next time(new launch of the app) be cos I use a splash screen for my launch

Comment: add the boolean in SQL database tables you created to store the question offline. So, when you update the table, boolean will be stored. So, when you launch the second time, you can randomize your query on index and filter it with boolean.

Answer (score 0):

By this code, you can have all 50 questions in a random position. Now, You have to display questions by its unique id in pages. To get 5 pages with 50 different questions use HashMap Array. Nice question. All the best.

```
public void generateNumbers() {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random randomnumber = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            int random = randomnumber.nextInt(49);
            randomnumber.nextInt(49);
            if (!numbers.contains(random)) {//Set Non Repeatong Value
                numbers.add(random);
            }
        }//After this execution size may be less then 50

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (numbers.size() != 50) {
                if (!numbers.contains(i)) {
                    numbers.add(i);
                }
            }
        }// Size will be 50 all 50 questions are in array list
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Numbers are " + convertToString(numbers) + " Size " + numbers.size());
    }
```